# keypressevent and its overload

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have a following class which handles escape key press.

```
         class KeyPress : public QWidget
       {
           Q_OBJECT
          public:
            KeyPress(QWidget * parent=0);

          protected:
             void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);

       };
```

And the .cpp file:

```
          void KeyPress::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
           {

                if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {
                    qApp->quit();
                           }
            }
```

It works fine, but if I change the method's name, to say, `keyPressed(QKeyEvent * event)`, it doesn't work. The `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)` method according to docs is a protected method of `QWidget`. 
  So the initial code just overloads that method, dosn't it? And the overload works. But why a completely new version of the method with another name but the same implementation wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `overload`, it is `override` of `virtual` function.
Read about `c++` `virtual` functions.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
struct Foo { /*virtual*/void f() { cout << "foo:f\n"; } };
struct Boo : public Foo { void f() { cout << "boo:f\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Boo boo;
    Foo *ptr = &boo;
    ptr->f();
}
```

such code print `foo:f`, because of for `ptr->f()` compiler  generate something like this:

```
address_of_function = &Foo::f;
call address_of_function
```

but if you uncomment `virtual` in my example code will print `boo:f`,
because of `virtual` cause compiler generate similar to such code:

```
 address_of_function = ptr->virtual_table_of_Foo_class[offset_of_f]
 call address_of_function
```

`ptr` point to Boo class virtual table, and `address_of_function` will be equal `&Boo::f`, this how `virtual` functions works.

So in your case `Foo` == `QWidget` and it have code like this inside of `Qt`:

```
this->keyPressEvent();
```

, which take address of `keyPressEvent` in virtual table, and call it. Obviously if you implement `KeyPress::someOtherFunction`, it will be not called, because of already compiled code of `Qt` have no call to it.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I mean. Meant override, the different implementation of parent's function, the same signature. But the question still stands. Why a new method doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for a reply! But its still not completely clear. Isn't my situation the same as if there was a `f2()` function in `Boo` which would have done the same thing as `f()` which is `cout<<"foo:f\n`. So there shoud be nothing wrong with `Boo` object calling that function...

Comment: But `Qt` know only about `Foo::f`, and when user input event is handled `Qt` call only call it, it can call only `Foo::f`, because of it have no idea about  `Boo::f2`.

Comment: The compiler generate calls to function based on names of function, not content of function.